# Does solute concentration vary significantly with depth?

Tags: physical-chemistry, home-experiment

If I dissolve glucose in an ordinary beaker filled with water, are the concentrations of glucose at the top and bottom significantly different? What if we use NaCl as the solute? Is there a molecule large enough to ``sink'' to the bottom, and if so would it still be classified as a solute? Likewise, are there solutes which are lighter than H2O, so they float upwards?

Comment: theres a famous experiment where you dissolve salt without mixing in an aquarium to obtain a gradient of refractive index, and so bending of light rays passing through. Im not sure but i guess as the salt dissolves stronger concentration falls to the bottom

Comment: here: https://youtu.be/PAK_1C-Zqo0

Answer (score 5):

> **(1)If I dissolve glucose in an ordinary beaker filled with water, are the concentrations of glucose at the top and bottom significantly different?**
>
> **(2) What if we use NaCl as the solute?**

1 & 2 are basically the same question. The difference in gravity between the top of the beaker and the bottom of the beaker is real but insignificant. So due to gravity alone there won't be a concentration gradient.

However there are solutions which can be centrifuged which will create a concentration gradient. Essentially the centrifuge creates a large gravity gradient. Close to center gives lower gravity, far from center gives higher gravity. Once you stop the centrifuge however the concentration gradient is not at equilibrium. So over time the concentration gradient would disappear.

> **(3) Is there a molecule large enough to ``sink'' to the bottom, and if so would it still be classified as a solute?**

The above discussion about a centrifuge confirms the basic notation, but there is an unstable gradient, not a sinking per se.

Obviously if you drop a marble in a glass of water it sinks. But the marble isn't *dissolved* in the water.

> **(4) Likewise, are there solutes which are lighter than H2O, so they float upwards?**

This is a bit more interesting. Open a plastic bottle of soda and put a balloon over the neck of the bottle.  Carbon dioxide was dissolved in the soda under pressure. When the soda is opened, the pressure is released and the excess carbon dioxide will "float up" out of the soda and blowup the balloon. Since the gas phase is less dense than the liquid phase (soda) it is on top. The gas doesn't really "float" on the soda however. It is also important to realize that once equilibrium is established the carbon dioxide remaining in the soda is homogeneously distributed throughout the soda.

A different sort of twist are soap molecules which will "float" to the surface, not because they are lighter, but because of the surface tension of water. The famous soap/pepper experiment illustrates this.

Another sort of twist here is a bartender who makes fancy cocktails by floating one layer of a liquor over another due to the higher layers being less dense. The segregation of the layers is unstable however. One good swirl with a straw and the layers mix.

---

For 3 and 4 there is what is called a *phase diagram*. For example it shows if two liquids will mix, or if there will be two phases where one liquid would float on the other.

Think of gasoline and water. There is a gasoline layer floating on the water so there are two liquid phases because there is an interface. However a very tiny amount of gasoline will be dissolved in the water and a very tiny amount of water will be dissolved in the gasoline. In this case the gasoline that is dissolved in the water is distributed homogeneously throughout the water. Likewise the water dissolved in the gasoline is distributed throughout the gasoline.

> *I used gasoline as a conceptual example. Gasoline however isn't a pure compound but rather a mixture. So for those that want to be picky substitute n-hexane for gasoline.*

Comment: Good point about the presence or absence of intermolecular interactions. However, e.g. dissolved oxygen will not rise or sink in a lake due to difference in mass or density. Also, the barometric formula does not rely on changes in gravity in different layers of the atmosphere - it is just a Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: "But since the gas is less dense than the liquid it will flow out of the liquid." This is potentially really misleading. Carbon dioxide *gas* (or oxygen gas or nitrogen gas) is less dense than water, but is *carbon dioxide* (or oxygen or nitrogen )  dissolved in water less dense than water?

Comment: @KarstenTheis - Thanks for pointing out the problem with fix the gas/liquid example. I've tried to fix it. // I thought about using the atmosphere as an example of a density gradient due to gravity, but there is also a huge temperature difference.

Comment: @BuckThorn - Thanks for pointing out the problem. I definitely wrote that part badly. I've tried to fix it. // The density of carbonated water is interesting. A [study](https://escholarship.org/content/qt6dn022hb/qt6dn022hb.pdf) found that it is. I didn't study the part on partial molar volumes carefully, but I'd expect that a carbon dioxide molecule tends to replace a water molecule. Since CO2 is heavier than H2O the density would go up. But that would also mean that the volume of the solution would increase when carbon dioxide is injected too.

Comment: Yes, there is a gravity gradient within a centrifuge tube—the centrifugal acceleration increases with the distance from the axis of rotation. However, the reason a centrifuge creates a density-based concentration gradient isn't that there's a gravity gradient. Rather, it's that the centrifugal acceleration is so high. I.e. what matters is how high the acceleration is, not that it varies. Indeed, you'd get *more* of a concentration gradient with an acceleration that was a constant, say, 10^5 g from top to bottom, than you would if it were 10^5 g at the bottom of the tube and <10^5 g at the top.

Answer (score 2):

In order to "see" the effects you are interested in you will have to forget the beaker. So we need to think at a very large scale. So instead of beaker, consider the Earth and its atmosphere. Air is a very nice example of a solution which is homogeneous mixture of nitrogen, oxygen, carbon dioxide, water in gas phase, noble gases (He, Ne, Kr, Rn, etc.) and some rare gases (H2 etc) . You might wish to consider nitrogen as the solvent and the rest as solutes. Guess why there is no hydrogen in the atmosphere and why helium is so rare in the atmosphere? Helium is continuously being produced by radioactive decay in rocks. Because these gases are so light that they "float upward" i.e., Earth's gravitational pull  is not strong enough on these small gases and they escape into the universe. This is why helium is so expensive. So this partially fulfills your molecules floating upward example.

Now comings to making some heavier molecules settle downwards in a solution. Take the example of air again and carbon dioxide. You can actually pour carbon dioxide over candles and they can be extinguished.
[image: candle extinguished]

As you would have guessed now, you either need very large scale system or very powerful gravitational field in order see the effects you wish to see. There are devices are ultra-centrifuges, which can achieve the separation of heavier molecules from the lighter molecules by differences in their weight. Earth's gravitational pull is not strong enough where you can observe dissolved glucose or NaCl settling to the bottom of a beaker. You can only see these effects with much larger molecules, so called macromolecules.

Comment: There are two issues that need to be carefully separated: density of samples with different composition (aquarium example from OP and CO2 example here), and separation from a homogeneous mixture (hydrogen example).

Comment: H/He is an interesting example, but the composition of the atmosphere is much more complicated of course. http://wordpress.mrreid.org/2014/08/01/the-composition-of-earths-atmosphere-with-elevation/

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question -- clearly marbles sink and molecules dissolve, and we don't commonly encounter objects between those length scales. It is helpful to look at colloids here, which are small particles of between 1nm and 1000nm, which means they're in-between the realm of molecules and of macroscopic objects. Since we can observe them with an ordinary microscope, they're often used as "super atoms".

You can get suspensions of colloids in water (they form when you add water to aniseed flavoured spirits, for example). In a very simple case, a colloid particle has two features affecting its energy: gravity, $mgh$, and thermal energy $k_\text{B} T$. Some particles will randomly have more thermal energy,
and thereby be able to float higher.

We can calculate the balance of these two energies with a Boltzmann distribution, which says the concentration of colloid particles at a height $ h $ compared to the concentration of colloid particles at the bottom is given by
$$ \frac{\eta(h)}{\eta(0)} = \exp\left(-\frac{mgz}{k_\text{B} T}\right)$$

Famously, Jean Baptise Perrin used this equation to calculate a value of $k_\text{B} T$ in 1916, which helped him [earn the Nobel Prize in 1926.](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1926/perrin/facts/)

We can put some numbers into this equation now. What height of beaker would we need to see 10% fewer particles at the top than at the bottom?

- For a virus of mass $1\times 10^{-17}\text{kg}$, we'd need a beaker that was 0.04mm tall to see 10% less at the top than the bottom.
- For a protein of mass $ 5\times 10^{-18}\text{kg}$, we'd need a beaker that was 8mm tall to see 10% less at the top than the bottom.
- For a glucose molecule of mass $ 2.98\times 10^{-25} \text{kg}$, we'd need a beaker that was 149 metres tall to see 10% less at the top and the bottom.
- For sodium chloride, we'd need a beaker 1170m tall to see 10% less $\text{Na}^+$ at the top than at the bottom!

Putting that last point in perspective, if we had a 10cm tall beaker full of salt in water, we'd find that the concentration of $\text{Na}^+$ at
the top was $99.99991\%$ of the concentration at the bottom -- it's such a small difference that we can ignore it. For glucose, the top of a 10cm beaker would have $99.9929\%$ of the concentration at the top compare to the bottom.

Comment: This would be true in vacuum, I think. However, none of these particles would be in the gas phase, they would all form solids (at least at room temperature and for an appreciable number of particles). In solution, you have to consider not the mass, but the difference in density (buoyancy). To sediment large proteins in solution, you need an ultracentrifuge (where particles experience on the order of 200,000 x g acceleration).